# How to bind to current riacontext user in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, wcf-ria-services

I Have a datacontext that has a "getuserbyguid" method, i want to pass in the current logged in user.userid as a parameter, but I don't know how to bind to the current logged in user through xaml. I've tried `{Binding Path=User.UserId}` but without any luck. I'm using the built in riaservices authentication methods, so the userinfo should be exposed in the riacontext, or am I wrong about this?

I have this for instance

```
<riaControls:DomainDataSource x:Name="FollowingGridData" AutoLoad="True" QueryName="GetUsersFollowedByIDQuery" LoadSize="20">
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <my:NotesDomainContext />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
            <riaControls:Parameter ParameterName="userguid" Value="{Binding Path=User.UserId}" />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource>
```

But it gives me an error saying that it's not a guid, meaning that it must not be binding correctly

Comment: It's not really supposed to be that hard is it? I mean - it seems like a pretty common scenario to me.

Comment: I'm now trying {Binding Path=CurrentUser.UserId, Source={StaticResource Application.Current}} but I get an error saying cannot find a resource with the name/key application.current silverlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct binding was

> {Binding Source={StaticResource
>   WebContext}, Path=User.DisplayName}